# salesforce lightning this.template.querySelector not working

Tags: salesforce-lightning

```
<template>
    <div class="container-wrapper">
            <div if:false={loggedIn} class="slds-m-around_medium">
                    <span>Login to Salesforce App</span>
                    <lightning-input name='username' label="Username"></lightning-input>
                   <lightning-input type="password" name='password' label="Password"></lightning-input>
                   <br/>
                   <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Login" title="Login" onclick={login}></lightning-button>
           </div>
</div>
</template>
  login() {
        console.log('login attempt');
        console.log(this.template);
         var Username =this.template.querySelector('input[name="username"]').value;
        var Password =this.template.querySelector('input[name="password"]').value;
        console.log(Password);
        console.log(Username );
}
```

values are not getting fetch in username, password variables.
this.template.querySelector('input[name="username"]').value is not working.

I have also tried onchange event approach on lightning-input elements , in that case event.target was undefined ? I am stuck not able to read user input.

[app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hhPU.png)

Answer (score 3):

There is no property 'name' on lightning-input like on standard HTML input. You should use 'data-id' instead.

HTML:

```
<lightning-input data-id='username' label="Username"></lightning-input>
```

JS:

```
let username = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input[data-id=username]');
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine. Should be marked as accepted.

Comment: Using something like: 

  <lightning-input-field
          field-name="ABC__c"
          data-field="abcField"
        >

and: 

this.template.querySelector("[data-field='abcField']").value

also works and is a bit more concise.

Comment: Using something like: 

  <lightning-input-field
          field-name="ABC__c"
          data-field="abcField"
        >

and: 

this.template.querySelector("[data-field='abcField']").value

also works and is a bit more concise.

Comment: Using something like: 

  <lightning-input-field
          field-name="ABC__c"
          data-field="abcField"
        >

and: 

this.template.querySelector("[data-field='abcField']").value

also works and is a bit more concise.

Answer (score -1):

The `<template>` element is not a common element. It holds its (inactive) DOM content inside a Document Fragment that you can access through the `content` property.

Therefore you should try:

```
    var Username = this.template.content.querySelector('input[name="username"]').value;
    var Password = this.template.content.querySelector('input[name="password"]').value;
```

Comment: his.template.content is undefined ? @Supersharp

Comment: @AjayKelkar I don't know how you fill this value. It depends on your code you didn't show

Comment: its user input in textbox, it runs under popout utlity. Look at app screenshot in above question

Answer (score -1):

In Salesforce when you are accessing a lightning input using the query selector first you have to search for lightning-input tag not the input tag.

Secondly when you add a name attribute to the lightning-input that attribute is transfered to the input tag which is created when the lightning component is rendered. But you can not access the input tag (my assumption is that it's in the Shadow DOM). Therefore to search for the lighting-input you must use a class name to identify the lightning component.

```
<lightning-input type="number" class="optionEditQuantityVal" value={Quantity} variant="label-hidden" step="1" max-length="1"></lightning-input>

let input = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input.optionEditQuantityVal')
```